# Oldest Exercising Equipments

Tags: ancient-history

What is the oldest exsistence of physical exercising equipments found in world, through literary evidences or archaeological  excavations?

Answer (score 6):

The 4th-5th century A.D. "Bikini Girls" mosaic from the Villa del Casale of Piazza Armerina shows female athletes [practicing or competing](http://www.penn.museum/blog/museum/women-can-also-play-sports-some-sports/) in athletic competition with dumbbells and a big ball that looks like a medicine ball (both in upper-left).

[image]

Without knowing the materials used to make that ball, it's hard to tell how heavy it would be. This [site](http://www.aerobiologicalengineering.com/wxk116/Roman/BallGames/) goes over the possibilities:

> The Romans had several different types of balls for their games --
>   hard balls, soft balls, bouncing balls, large balls and small balls.
>   They even had a glass ball and a ball of stone the size of a bowling
>   ball was found in Pompeii. At least six distinct types of balls can be
>   identified . . . The two types of follis most certainly bounced. The
>   paganica and harpastum did not. Balls made of wool would have bounced
>   poorly. **The two balls [below] were found in an Egyptian tomb from the
>   Roman period and are about 5" in diameter. Notice the striking
>   similarity to the Bikini Girls ball. They are made of linen and hair
>   wrapped in string and sewn together.** These wouldn't have bounced well
>   but were probably used for games like Trigon, harpasta, or Field
>   Hockey.

[image]

Comment: While it is indeed an interesting answer, 4-5th Century AD? Are there no older ones found?

Comment: @Rohit: It's the oldest solid evidence I've been able to find so far. I followed a few other leads, but they aren't well sourced.